# How to input multiple lines of a paragraph in c and sort according to the number present in lines

Tags: c, sorting, output, getline

How to input multiple lines of paragraph and sort according to the number present in the lines in C/C++ (recommended).
For example:

```
New Service 23 44
Center Hall 11 43
Bharat Airline Hall 45 9
```

We have to sort them on the basis of let's suppose first number i.e 23 for line first, 11 for second, 45 for third.

I have tried structure but it is not working maybe `getline` function can get some help with it.

```c
int main(void)
{
    int maxLineCount = 500, maxCharCount = 500, i, j, count;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size;

    char *a[maxLineCount];
    for (i = 0; i < maxLineCount; i++)
        a[i] = (char *)malloc(maxCharCount * sizeof(char));


    int noOfLine = 0;
    // read the input as line
    while(getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1) {
        strcpy(a[noOfLine++],line);
    }



    for(i = 1; i < noOfLine; i++)
      printf("%s", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Result should be the sorted line on the basis of the number.
Required output:

```
Center Hall : 11 43
New Service : 23 44
Bharat Airline : 45 9
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++ — the idiomatic answers in the two languages are both wholly different.  What works best in C++ won't work at all in C; what is necessary in C is wholly inappropriate for C++.  Do not dual tag questions with both C and C++ without a much better reason.  Note that using `malloc()` etc suggests you're really using C, not C++.  Good C++ programs rarely if ever use `malloc()`.

Comment: `for(i = 1; i < noOfLine; i++)` should be `for(i = 0; i < noOfLine; i++)`. Using C you may use the `qsort` (see: man qsort or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/ ) before the last for.

Comment: Please, post the code regarding your attempt of sorting the lines (likely a regex of some sort?)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can write a "split" function to extract the index from a line using [string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [string::substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) :

```
void split(const std::string str, std::vector<std::string>& result, char sep = ' ') {

   std::size_t cur, prev = 0;

   cur = str.find(sep);

   while (cur != std::string::npos) {
      result.push_back(str.substr(prev, cur - prev));

      prev = cur + 1;

      cur = str.find(sep, prev);
   }

   result.push_back(str.substr(prev, cur - prev));
}
```

Then make use of the [multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) to store the lines in sorted order.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   std::string line;

   std::multimap<int, std::string> sortedLines;

   while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
      std::vector<std::string> splitLine;

      split(line, splitLine, ' ');

      int splitCount = splitLine.size();

      if (splitCount < 2) break;

      int index = std::atoi(splitLine[splitCount - 2].c_str());

      sortedLines.insert({ index, line });
   }
```

Then you can simply output the content of the multimap.

```
   for (auto l : sortedLines) {
      std::cout << l.second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

---

Entire source:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

void split(const std::string str, std::vector<std::string>& result, char sep = ' ') {

   std::size_t cur, prev = 0;

   cur = str.find(sep);

   while (cur != std::string::npos) {
      result.push_back(str.substr(prev, cur - prev));

      prev = cur + 1;

      cur = str.find(sep, prev);
   }

   result.push_back(str.substr(prev, cur - prev));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   std::string line;

   std::multimap<int, std::string> sortedLines;

   while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
      std::vector<std::string> splitLine;

      split(line, splitLine, ' ');

      int splitCount = splitLine.size();

      if (splitCount < 2) break;

      int index = std::atoi(splitLine[splitCount - 2].c_str());

      sortedLines.insert({ index, line });
   }

   for (auto l : sortedLines) {
      std::cout << l.second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C code below allows you to enter lines and to sort them on the basis of the first integer positive number found in the inserted lines.

I've solved some issues (memory related and other - you may see the differences) I've found in your code. In the code you may also note I've used the function`fgets` instead of the function `getline`.

To sort the lines (the array containing them) I've used the `qsort` function.

The qsort function operates calling the function `compare` (the name could be different. It's a programmer choice).

The function `compare` is specified in the qsort parameters and shall be written in the C-code by the code-writer.

The function `compare` is called by the function `qsort` to understand the "direction" of all the necessary comparisons to sort the elements.

If you want an ascending sort, the function `compare` shall return:

- 0 if the compared elements are equal
- n<0 if the first element is smaller than the second
- n>0 if the first element is greater than the second.

Look at [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) to have info about the function qsort.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const char * s1=*(const char * const *)a, * s2=*(const char *const *)b;
    const char * ptr;
    int n1, n2;

    ptr=s1;
    while(*ptr && !isdigit(*ptr) ) ptr++;
    n1=(int)strtol(ptr,NULL,10);

    ptr=s2;
    while(*ptr && !isdigit(*ptr) ) ptr++;
    n2=(int)strtol(ptr,NULL,10);

    if ( !(n1-n2) ) {
        return strcmp(s1,s2);
    }

    return n1-n2;
}

int main(void)
{    
    size_t maxLineCount = 500,i;
    unsigned int maxCharCount = 500;
    size_t noOfLine = 0;

    char ** a;

    a=malloc(maxLineCount * sizeof(char *));
    if (!a)
       return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < maxLineCount; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(maxCharCount);
        if (!a[i]) 
            return -2;
    }

    // read the input lines till ctrl-D (Linux) or ctrl-Z (Windows)
    // or maxLineCount is reached.
    while( fgets(a[noOfLine], (int)maxCharCount, stdin) && ++noOfLine<maxLineCount);

    qsort(a,noOfLine,sizeof(char *),compare);

    for(i = 0; i < noOfLine; i++)
      printf("%s", a[i]);

    // Release memory
    if (a) {          
        for(i = 0; i < noOfLine; i++)
            free(a[i]);
        free(a);
    }

    // exit
    return 0;
}
```